# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'corr'

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

```
correlation_matrix = pd.corr()
# cannot = True to print the values inside the square
sns.heatmap(data=correlation_matrix, annot=True)
```

In spite of using the header file it is showing the error

Comment: `corr()` is a method on dataframe objects, not on the pandas module directly.

Comment: I am using this in google colab

Answer (score 1):

I dont think pandas has corr(), it is suppose to be dataframes more like df.corr()
Maybe this will help https://datatofish.com/correlation-matrix-pandas/